# Lao-Tseu carved statue signed sigillary caracters

Tags: meaning, transcription

[image: Cette photo représente peut-être le livre du YiKing . IL est ouvert sur une carapace de tortue, ce qui fait référence aux premières écritures chinoises. La statue montre Lao-Tseu avec cette tortue, un sabre et le texte.]Hi,
Perhaps it is better I open a special file for my question?
Lao-Tseu or Confucius holding the sacred YiKing book?
Material is a kind of hard stone.[image: statue Yiking holding by Lao-Tseu]

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 3):

The carving on the piece is from a poem called **On Reading History** (《咏史》) by Gao Shi (高适) from the Tang Dynasty.

The text is as follows:

> 尚有绨袍赠，应怜范叔寒。
>
> 不知天下士，犹作布衣看。

This is a simplified version of the traditional characters above.

A translation by Xu Yuanchong and Xu Ming renders it as:

> The envoy gave a silken gown
>
> To one on whom he looked down,
>
> Mistaking the prime minister
>
> For a poor plain-clothed commoner.

It has nothing to do with either Lao-Tseu or Confucius.

Comment: maybe you can give me in chinese caracters the title of tho poem and the book I try to read the story of this poor plain-clothed

Comment: my email is jfbaeta14(@)yahoo.fr